# Why do we explicitly mention testing environment property for jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I was going through [jest configuration docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) and other tutorials for setting up Jest, they have one thing common which is

```
  module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

***Can somebody explain to me WHY are we needing this property, what is the use of it, how does it affect jest functionality?***

Answer (score 2):

Different environments are different.

If you test a script that uses `require()` in JSDOM then it is going to fail.

If you test a script that uses `document.querySelector()` in Node then it is going to fail.

Comment: I see, so basically we are teaching jest that you are expected to have for eg document.querySelector () for JSDOM, thanks for the explanation.